# unable to set value in shared preference on check box selection

Tags: android

```
public class FragSettings extends SherlockFragment {
    CheckBox notificationcheckbox;
    Button savebutton;
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    Editor editor;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        preferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(
                AppConstants.LOGIN_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_settings, container, false);
        notificationcheckbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        savebutton = (Button) container.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("NotifcationValue", "1");

        addListenerOnChkWindows();

        return view;
    }

    public void addListenerOnChkWindows() {

        notificationcheckbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (notificationcheckbox.isChecked()) {

                    Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("NotifcationValue", "1");

                    editor.commit();

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "On", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }

                else {
                    editor.putString("NotifcationValue", "0");
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();

                }
            }
        });

    }

}
```

here is my code i want set value on Cehcbox Enable value should set 1 in shared preference and check box disable value should set 0 i have tried but i am able to set value in but on check box disable value is not setting 0 please look my code and tell me where is issue please suggest me code .

Answer (score 2):

You should commit `preferences` after adding string.

```
 editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missed

```
 editor.commit();
```

in `else` body

that too Use `onCheckedChangeListener` instead of `onClickListener` for `CheckBox`

like this

```
notificationcheckbox
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                        editor.putString("NotifcationValue", "1");
                        editor.commit();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "On",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        editor.putString("NotifcationValue", "0");
                        editor.commit();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Off",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            });
```

Comment: thanx can u please tell me toggle button and check box is same ?

Comment: yes..both extends the Compound button and functionality is also same.http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html

Comment: how to apply condition for another check box we have to check box in both selection i am inserting value to sharecropped.  here is my code http://pastie.org/9767323  @kalyan pvs

Comment: @Edge post it as another question

Comment: no both are different but toggle button is also implements using check change listener

Answer (score 0):

```
 please use onCkeck change listener with check box like

    public class FragSettings extends SherlockFragment {
        CheckBox notificationcheckbox;
        Button savebutton;


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {



            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_settings, container, false);
            notificationcheckbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            savebutton = (Button) container.findViewById(R.id.button1);


            addListenerOnChkWindows();

            return view;
        }

        public void addListenerOnChkWindows() {


    notificationcheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {


    if(isChecked)
    {
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("Notificationpref", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString("NotifcationValue", "1");
            editor.commit();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "On", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
    }
    else
    {
      SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("Notificationpref", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString("NotifcationValue", "0");
            editor.commit();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
    }

                }
            });




        }

    }
```

Comment: how to apply condition for another check box we have to check box in both selection i am inserting value to sharecropped. here is my code http://pastie.org/9767323  @Rohit Heera